# URL for accessing different versions of a web application on tomcat?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, url

I have a web application configured as /myApp

Every time I push a new release, I am planning to deploy a new application version by renaming the war file a myApp##002 which results in /myApp##0002

The URL on my client: http://mywebsite.edu/myApp points to the latest version of my web application. Sometimes if the release contains some major bugs that impact only a part of our users we want the ability to direct them to the previous version of our website.

Now, I have created another version of my client that I want to point to the previous version of the web application instead but I am not sure how to do that. Can someone please shed some light on this? Thanks.